How to setup a timeout on sqlalchemy using polars
I'm running a for loop through a DataFrame, but some queries are taking longer than expected, causing the process to finish prematurely. I would like to add a condition that if the connection takes more than 'n' seconds, the loop should skip to the next value in the DataFrame. Additionally, I want to mark the row with a 'timeout' value in a specific column.
My code:
import polars as pl
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table , select, func, case, literal_column, literal, distinct, and_, or_, extract

E27V422024= create_engine('mssql://'+'xd'+'/'+'WMBDP2024'+'?trusted_connection=yes&driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server',
                          pool_size= 0, max_overflow=0
                        )


concatenated_df = pl.DataFrame()

for row in first_five_rows.to_dicts():
    rut = row['Rut']
    fechaI = row['FechaEnvio']
    fechaO = row['FechaTermino']

    # Execute the query and store the result in a temporary DataFrame
    temp_df = pl.read_database(f"""
    SELECT
        rut,
        codtran,
        coderr,
        monto,
        fecha
    FROM database
    WHERE rut = {rut} AND fecha BETWEEN '{fechaI}' AND '{fechaO}'
    AND codtran IN ('MPMR80', 'MPMR22', 'SCULOE')
    """, connection=E27V422024.connect())
    if temp_df.shape[0] == 0:
        data = {"rut": rut,
        "codtran": 'nop',
        "coderr": 'nop',
        "monto": 8888,
        "fecha":fechaI}

        data_df = pl.DataFrame(data, schema={"rut": pl.Int64(),
                                            "codtran": pl.String(),
                                            "coderr": pl.String(),
                                            "monto": pl.Decimal(),
                                            "fecha": pl.Datetime()}, strict=False)

        temp_df = data_df
    else:
        pass
    

    concatenated_df = pl.concat([concatenated_df, temp_df])


print(concatenated_df)

Any advice to sole this issue would be really appreciated
I searched and i have found some code with libraries like psycopg2 and gevent. However i think there are an easy way to solve this issue.
Some extra info:
Im using polars, the server is on microsoft sql server.
Update:
I just added to the create_enige the following:
create_engine('base',pool_size= 0, max_overflow=0, connect_args={'timeout': 2})

Now my process its not beeing canceled, however, i still to save the values that return a TimeOut.
